# Writing Data through Pin at certain frequency

Tags: arduino-uno, frequency, sound

I have an Arduino UNO which is connected to an KLZ25 board, the Arduino sends an 1MHz Clock at Pin 9 and now I should write the PDM-Data with 1 Mhz at pin 8. But i don't know how to write with such a speed, because if I write in the Loop:

```
loop{
digitalWrite(1); 
digitalWrite(0);
}
```

I get only a frequency of 36Khz, I know it depends on the count of commands in the loop, but I don't know how to write with a certain frequency in my case 1Mhz.

I get the PDM-Data (pulse density modulation) in form of 1 and 0 from a python script on a Host-PC and now I want to stream the Data with 1MHz to an other developer board which makes further calculation with the PDM-Data. I store the PDM-Data in queues because I have not enough memory to store the whole Data.

Does anybody know how to write PDM-Data with a 1MHz frequency to an output pin ?

Comment: What does the acronym PDM mean?  It would help to state it in your question.

Comment: Use one of the timers on the UNO. Those are the ones that are used for PWM. Set the prescaler to /8. Set the mode to fast-pwm. Set the output pin to no-inverting mode. Set OCxA/OCxB to 2 (since the timer runs at 2Mhz). Then change the TOP value based on the PDM value you want to send.

Comment: PDM means pulse density modulation, basically I write 1 or 0 with 1Mhz frequency. @Gerben What do you mean by TOP value ? Does the change of the timer changes also the loop speed because I don't get how to write in 1Mhz if the loop is slower.

Comment: DigitalWrite itself is super slow. It takes a lot of cycles. `loop` itself also takes a few cycle to get called. You could use direct port manipulation instead, which is a lot faster. But to run at 1Mhz, you only have 16 cycles to toggle the pin and run the loop, leaving you with nearly no time left to do anything else.  Also other interrupts could occur and slow your loop at "random" intervals, giving you a unstable 1Mhz signal. That's why I'm suggesting using timers, as they run in parallel.

Comment: The timer is for example used to PWM an LED. This timer runs parallel to your code. The timer has a counter that it increments every clock cycle. You can select a TOP value, so that, when it reaches this value, it reset the counter to zero. It also has a compare registers. You can instruct the timer that, once the counter reaches the value in the compare register it should set one of the output pins LOW. You can also instruct it to set the output pin HIGH when it's set back to zero. So by combining this the output will be HIGH for 1µs, followed by a number of µs LOW, depending on value of TOP.

Comment: You might also be able to emulate the desired behaviour with one of the atmegas interfaces (e.g. SPI master). The essence of what Gerben mentioned is that you should use the available hardware because as you already found out handling this stuff in `loop()` won't work at 1 MHz.

Comment: 16 CPU cycles is a _very short time_. You won't be able to do much other than the delta-sigma algorithm for generating the PDM output. Some time ago I wrote a program that does almost what you are asking for. It reads data in a “shift register” fashion and outputs it as PDM at 615 kHz with a CPU running at 8 MHz. That's 13 CPU cycles per PDM cycle. It's intended to run on an ATtiny13A and should be easy to adapt to an Uno. It's based on a carefully timed assembly loop, with no interrupts. Tell me if you are interested in me publishing it.

Comment: Ah ok I understand, thanks for the answers! @EdgarBonet that would be nice if you would publish it. I don't know if the SPI solution would work with the frdm-klz25 board but I will try to use the timer interrupt solution and if this don't fit I give it a try, thanks! And I don't must do the sigma delta modulation, I have done it on python on the Host-PC and I use the Arduino to send the Data to a KLZ25, basically the Arduino and the Host-PC together simulates a Microphone and on the KLZ25 I will do an MFCC calcuation after I streamed the PDM-Data from the PC to the Arduino.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to output a synchronous serial bit
stream at 1 MHz. Something like this:

```
        ___     ___     ___
clk  __/   \___/   \___/   \___⋅⋅⋅
     ______ _______ _______ ___
dat  __D0__X___D1__X___D2__X___⋅⋅⋅
```

where the data bits come from the PC.

If you want this to be a continuous bit stream, it will not be easy to
generate on an Arduino Uno.

### Receiving the data

Since the data comes from the PC, it comes presumably through the serial
link. You have to account for the fact that this link adds a start bit
and a stop bit to every byte. Thus, you have 10 bits on the wire
for every 8 bits of actual data. Since you have to sustain
1 Mb/s average of actual data, this means that you must configure
the serial port for at least 1.25 Mb/s. However, the only baud rate
higher that 1 Mb/s supported by the Arduino Uno is 2 Mb/s.

Does your PC support this baud rate? Is the communication reliable at
this speed?

If the speed is too high, I would suggest you try to have the PC send
the data as PCM at a lower speed, and have the Arduino handle the
PCM → PDM conversion.

### Transmitting the data

This data format is very similar to an SPI transmission. Then, the SPI
hardware port seems like the easiest way to generate it. However, the
SPI transmitter on the Uno is *not* double-buffered. This means that you
have to wait for the current byte transmission to be finished before
providing the next byte to the SPI hardware. This in turn means that you
will inevitably have small delays between consecutive bytes, and one out
of every 8 clock cycles will be stretched beyond the expected
1 µs. If this unsteadiness is acceptable for your application, then
do use the SPI transmitter. If not, you will have to find another
solution.

The serial port on the Uno has a special mode of operation where it
behaves like a master SPI port. Unlike the actual SPI port, this port is
double-buffered, which makes it possible to send a continuous bit stream
with a steady clock. The problem is, you cannot use this mode for
transmission and at the same time use the serial port receiver in its
regular asynchronous mode. Thus you will not be able to receive the data
from the PC when using this mode. If you can manage to route the
PC → Arduino communication through SPI, this mode of operation
of the serial port may be a good choice.

If none of the options above works for you I suggest, as last resort, to
generate the bitstream entirely by software. The timings are tight, as
each level of the clock has to be held for only 8 CPU cycles. But
it is likely doable in hand-written assembly, provided that interrupts
are disabled. Here is roughly how I may try to do that:

```lisp
    in output, _SFR_IO_ADDR(PORT_OUT)   ; save a copy of the port reg.

loop:
    lds data, _SFR_MEM_ADDR(UDR0)       ; load data from USART

    ; output bit 0
    andi output, ~_BV(1)                ; clear clock bit
    bst data, 0                         ; save data[0]
    bld output, 0                       ; load it into output[0]
    ; no delay needed here
    out _SFR_IO_ADDR(PORT_OUT), output  ; output
    ori output, _BV(1)                  ; set the clock bit
    delay 6                             ; assumed to be a macro
    out _SFR_IO_ADDR(PORT_OUT), output  ; output

    ; output bit 1
    andi output, ~_BV(1)                ; clear clock bit
    bst data, 1                         ; save data[1]
    bld output, 0                       ; load it into output[0]
    delay 4
    out _SFR_IO_ADDR(PORT_OUT), output  ; output
    ori output, _BV(1)                  ; set the clock bit
    delay 6
    out _SFR_IO_ADDR(PORT_OUT), output  ; output

    ; etc...

    rjmp loop
```

The code above assumes the UART is synchronized with the output stream,
which will likely not be the case in reality. Your real application may
then be more complex, and you will have to make that extra complexity
fit within the delay slots above.

Note that if you handle the PCM → PDM conversion on the
Arduino the resulting code may end up being simpler, as you will be able
to read the UART at every loop iteration without worrying about
synchronization. I have written a program that does something very
similar a while ago, and I just pushed it to GitHub for you to take a
look: [avr-dac: Turn an AVR into a 1-bit D/A converter](https://github.com/edgar-bonet/avr-dac). Note
that this program is meant to be usable on AVRs without a hardware UART.
It expects the PCM data to be fed in the fashion of a shift register.
Using the UART would make the program simpler.